# Unable to add a row to a section in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, insert, swift3, row

There is a favorites button within my custom cell. In the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` I set up a listener for whenever the favorites button is clicked. Right now, I have two sections. Section 0 is all foods and section 1 is favorites. When I get to endUpdates(), the app crashes with the `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception. The `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function is never called within `addFavorites`. `favoriteFoods` is initialized, and I've never called `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` anywhere else in my code.

```
func addFavorites(sender: UIButton) {
        let touchPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), to: companyTableView)
        let indexPath = companyTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)

        favorites.append(allFood[(indexPath?.row)!])

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: favoriteFoods.count - 1, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
        section: Int) -> Int {
        if (section == 0) {
            return allFood.count
        } else {
            return favorites.count
        }
    }
```

---

Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:1594

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: Please show your `numberOfRowsInSection` code; it isn't accurately reflecting the updated row count

Comment: edited, I also put a print statement in the else clause and it shows that the number of rows in the favorite section is being successfully increased to 1

Comment: You are adding the new row to an array called `favorites` but `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning the count of an array called `favoriteFoods`

Comment: is this `favorites.append` a typo and should be  `favoriteFoods.append`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo taken from old code. The working code I had has `favorites` for both

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add `companyTableView.insertSections([1], with: .automatic)` between begin and end updates because there was no pre-existing section.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the new row to an array called `favorites` but `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning the count of an array called `favoriteFoods`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo taken from old code. The working code I had has `favorites` for both

Comment: Try moving the `favorites.append(allFood[(indexPath?.row)!])` after the `beginUpdates`